# How to build differently for Linux vs Windows

Tags: go

I'm taking look on Go language.
And I have a question: for example I will create a new library, that should use methods from one Go package for Windows and from other for Linux.

I'm just asking, is there a convenient way of organizing build process?
Of course, I can just make a project for every OS and change import name for every OS.

Answer (score 6):

Use build constraints and file names. See [Package build](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/). The source code for [Package os](https://golang.org/pkg/os/) has many examples: https://golang.org/src/os/. Go Source Code: https://go.googlesource.com/go or https://github.com/golang/go.

A build contraint for Unix:

```
// +build darwin dragonfly freebsd linux nacl netbsd openbsd solaris
```

Some build file names:

```
stat_darwin.go     stat_linux.go   stat_openbsd.go  stat_unix.go
stat_dragonfly.go  stat_nacl.go    stat_plan9.go    stat_windows.go
stat_freebsd.go    stat_netbsd.go  stat_solaris.go
```

The Go tools and standard library started out using build file names and then, as the requirements became more complex, began using build constraints.